# Combine tables with different data

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables:

```
+--------+-----+
| name   | A   | 
+--------+-----+
|  abc   |   10|
|  def   |   17|
|  ghi   |   27|
+--------+-----+

+--------+-----+
| name   | B   | 
+--------+-----+
|  abc   |   9 |
|  def   |   55|
|  xyz   |   92|
+--------+-----+
```

Now I need to combine these two tables, that each name appears only once, but it has the result of A and B in it. If there is no matching entry than a zero should be displayed.

So the result should look like this:

```
+--------+-----+-----+
| name   | A   | B   |  
+--------+-----+-----+
|  abc   |   10|   9 |
|  def   |   17|   55|
|  ghi   |   27|   0 |
|  xyz   |   0 |   92|
+--------+-----+-----+
```

Later I might have a third table with **C** which should be added in the same way.

How would the SQL look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `full outer join`, which will preserve rows not joining on both tables. You can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) more details about this.

Your query should look like this

```
select  coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) name
        coalesce(t1.a, 0) a,
        coalesce(t2.b, 0) b
from    table1 t1
full outer join
        table2 t2
on      t1.name = t2.name
```

The `coalesce` function returns the first parameter or, if that is `null`, the second, and it's needed because if a row isn't joined, it will be preserved by the `outer join` but you'll have `null`s on it.

Comment: best solution, coalesce can be replaced by ifnull too

Answer (score 0):

```
select names.name, a.A, b.B
from (select name from tablea
      union 
      select name from tableb) names
  left join tablea a on a.name = names.name
  left join tableb b on b.name = names.name
```

Comment: Isn't this solution a bit overcomplicated? And it will return `null` instead of `0` on `A` and `B` for the rows that aren't joined by the `left join`s.

Comment: Yes, I missed the zero requirement comment. And this could be addressed using `coalesce`, as you did. But even so, absent client business reqs, that seems wrong to me. If no record exists, value is not zero, it is simply not there. Null is better.  I believe that  zero requirement possibly due to misunderstanding of nature of data.  As to complexity, that depends on your interpretation/perception. Conceptually, it seems simpler to me. First create distinct list of all Names, then use that to fetch other data values.  That represents the logical problem with more clarity than full joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    create table TableA(Name varchar(3),A int)
    create table TableB(Name varchar(3),B int)

    insert into TableA values('abc',10)
    insert into TableA values('def',17)
    insert into TableA values('ghi',27)

    insert into TableB values('abc',9)
    insert into TableB values('def',55)
    insert into TableB values('xyz',92)


    select ISNULL(TableA.Name,TableB.Name),ISNULL(A,0),ISNULL(B,0) from TableA
    full outer JOIN TableB ON TableA.Name=TableB.Name
```

If there are more than two tables use 'coalesce()' Function instead of ISNULL

Like This if we add another third table :

```
    create table TableC(Name varchar(3),C int)

    insert into TableC values('abc',9)
    insert into TableC values('def',55)
    insert into Tablec values('LMN',92)


    select  coalesce(t1.name, t2.name,t3.name) name,
    coalesce(t1.a, 0) a,
    coalesce(t2.b, 0) b,
    coalesce(t3.C,0) C
    from TableA t1
    full outer JOIN TableB t2 ON t1.Name=t2.Name
    full outer JOIN TableC t3 ON t1.Name=t3.Name or  t2.Name=t3.Name
```

Comment: I think you could even use coalesce in the last join `full outer JOIN TableC t3 ON coalesce(t1.Name, t2.name)=t3.Name`

Answer (score 0):

```
select abc as name,1 as a into #table1 
select ayz as name,1 as b into #table2

SELECT 
z.name,
isnull(#table1.A, 0),
isnull(#table2.B, 0)
FROM
(SELECT name FROM #table1
UNION
SELECT name FROM #table2) AS Z
left join #table1 on #table1.name = z.name
left join #table2 on #table2.name = z.name
```